# Which rails association to record duel participants and the winner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing a duel system between a hero and a monster

Actually i have 3 Active Record Models :

```
class Hero < ActiveRecord::base
  has_many: duels
end

class Monster < ActiveRecord::base
   has_many: duels
end

class Duel < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :hero
  belongs_to :monster
end
```

And i would like to record the winner in the duel model. Which Active Record Association would you use for that ? I could use a polymorphic association in the Duel model but it would create a has_many in Monster/Hero models... that sounds bad ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a duel is always between a hero and a monster then you could just add a field "winner" to the duels table, which can only be set to "hero" or "monster", and then set it appropriately when someone wins.

Comment: And the winner field could even be named "resolution" and allow for other situations like draw, monster escape, hero escape etc...